# How to realign columns in two data sets in Excel2013

Tags: microsoft-excel

The figure below explains what I am trying to do:

[image: Image of 'Data now & What I would like']

I have movement from different experiments and I would like to line up the data when a stimulus starts (indicated by the change from `0` to `1` in the top row of each table). This is different in every experiment and currently I am doing the lining up by hand.  I thought that there must be a cleverer/quicker method.

The raw data is quite large (meaning >9000 columns and roughly 100 rows), and the number of pre-stimulus observations can range from 5000 to 100 data points (columns). The goal is to shift/align the column of the bottom table to the first column with 1 in the top table (in the example, column U, but this column must be identified via a formula). The raw data has 6 of these tables and roughly 20 records per week (not a fixed number).

Comment: In your example, you've allowed for 4 pre-stimulus observations.  Will that cover all cases, or could you run into a case with more than 4?  Basically the goal is to shift the data so the first column with 1 for the week is in column U?  Are there always 4 observations per week or can the number of weekly records vary?

Comment: You can do this task with VBA script. But to be honest, the effort ist to high.. and usually somebody say in these comments below the question: "We are not a coding service." I guess it is a 30 line script, but there are also real coding guys on i.e. fiverr or similar platforms that code this for small money

Comment: After you get the required format - do you intend to do some mathematical operation across week 1 and week 2 data or is it just for visual purposes? If it is just for visual purposes - you can use tools within Excel like Pivot table etc. - *Add more information to your question please by editing your question*

Comment: Hi fixer1234. The raw data is quite large (meaning >9000 column and roughly 100 rows) and the amount of pre-observations can range from 5000 to 100 data points (column).  You are are totally right about the goal, (simply :-)) shift/align the column of the bottom table to the first column with 1 in the top table (in the example column U). The raw data has 6 of these tables and roughly 20 records per week.

Comment: @ Varon. Many thanks for your response. I just though this 'problem' must be dealt with by certain people and hoped for a standard code that would be possible to use. One idea I've come across y'day is that maybe people who work with large genetic datasets might have the same issues when trying to line up, e.g. base pairs. I'll let you know if I find something useful.

Comment: @ Prassana. I will indeed use the output for statistics.